# Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error

Tags: virtualhost, .htaccess, httpd, apache2

While entering my website via the main page (`example.com`) everything works fine. But when entering in `example.com/forums` I get a 500 Internal Error, and I see in the error_log it says the following:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.

Also, I know I can post the output of `httpd -S`, but it is really long and there are no spoiler blocks & and the formatting goes away, sorry.

This is my `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
 RewriteRule ^(data|js|styles|install) - [NC,L]
 RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
 RewriteBase /var/www/html
</IfModule>
```

**EDIT:** Do you need the virtualhost?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What is the `curl -v` output or developer tool output for that page? Specifically, we need HTTP headers there. What exactly is running under `/` and `/forums`?

Comment: I just enter on my web page with Chrome. I haven't quite understand what you meant in the second part, you can test it in live if you wish, https://mcwownetwork.net

Comment: What is the website about? What are the parts used to build it?

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your server config or other `.htaccess` files? The `RewriteBase` directive looks invalid - this takes a URL-path, not a filesystem path. `/var/www/html` looks like a filesystem path? But this would _always_ result in a 500 error (a different error) - so it makes me think there is something else going on here?

Comment: @Tero Kilkanen, just a normal Xenforo installation..? w3dk Yes, yes and i'm not really sure if its outside of the .htaccess

Comment: Your _edit_ showing the "virtual host" is not complete? It's also a bit odd? Do you have SSL cert installed? Why check `%{HTTPS}`? Where's the `RewriteEngine` directive?

Answer (score 0):

One issue here is that your `RewriteRule` matches every request, and rewrites it to `index.php`. So, a request to `index.php` gets rewritten also to `index.php`, ad infinitum. Except that Apache stops trying after detecting ten consecutive redirects.

You need to find out what exactly you want to rewrite, and then make a rule for that which does not loop back to itself.

Comment: That alone wouldn't result in a rewrite loop. The rewrite process stops when the URL passes through unchanged. But the earlier directives prevent any request for an existing file/directory being rewritten anyway.

Comment: Well,i actually googled a bit, since it looks that these Rewrite Rules use regex/ something similiar i just don't know the regex pattern, even if bad, i did a sort of copy-pasta. What i shall insert/modify?